# rails: different view templates for each model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, model, sti

I have a `Section` model with multiple subclasses: `TextSection`, `PictureSection`, etc. I use Single Table Inheritance and Rails 5.

Each section type is displayed differently, but I'd like to do something like this pseudo code in my view:

```
<% for @page.sections.each do |section|%>
  <%= section.display %>
<% end %>
```

and for the edition:

```
<% for @page.sections.each do |section|%>
  <%= section.display_form %>
<% end %>
```

What's the rails way to achieve this? Can I attach or embedd a template to the model?

Answer (score 0):

You could try having a partial for each section type (e.g `_text_section.html.erb`, `_picture_section.html.erb`) and as you load the template, you can have rails choose a partial based on the section type being loaded.